# Redirect to new tab via any method. (JS, Symfony PHP components, etc)

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, redirect

What I would like to do is to open a new link after setting a timer of 5 seconds on my "thank you" page. What I currently have right now is that the link that should be opened redirects on the same page. Is it possible to do this? What I was planning is to redirect the "thank you" page I have on my homepage while the new tab to be opened will be redirected to an external link. Thanks in advance. I've read solutions like the window.open but I think it isn't the one I'm looking for and most of the searches I encounter says that it doesn't allow it since it is treated as a "popup". Here is what I have now.

```
$(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location = $('#redirect-url').attr('data-redirect-url');
        }, 5000)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location = $('#redirect-url').attr('href','data-redirect-url');
    }, 5000)
})
```

The .attr requires two parameters (attribute, value to that attribute)

**EDIT**
to open a new window, i know just this:

```
window.open('pageIWant.html', '_blank');
```

But it can really be treated as a popup by some browsers

Comment: hmmm, my last shot, try the following code

 setTimeout(function () {
   window.location.href = "pageIWant.html"; 
}, 5000);

change the pageIWant to the link you need

Comment: redirects on the same window buddy. Trying to make it work with window.open

Comment: so, try to use:
_window.open('pageIWant.html', '_blank');_

i know that you said something about 'PopUp', but I think it's the only way...

Comment: Apparently, There is no way to "bypass" popup that opens a window/tab programatically. Thanks for trying to help anyway. :)

Comment: you're welcome, if it helped just a little, please upvote or mark as correct :)